# My value is not changing in my set function

Tags: c++, arrays, getter-setter

The value of `n` is being passed to my `void Cell::setValue(int value)` function but `m_value` does not change. Can anyone explain what is wrong here?

File read in

```
void SudokuPuzzle::readPuzzle(const char filenameIn[]) {
// Add code to read in a puzzle from the text file and store within the SudokuPuzzle object
ifstream inStream;
inStream.open(filenameIn);


for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
        int n;
        inStream >> n;
        m_grid[i][j].setValue(n);
    }
}
```

Set value in cell

```
void Cell::setValue(int value)
{
    m_value = value;

    if (m_value = 0)
    {
        m_given = true;
    }
}
```

For example when `n` is set to `3` it is passed through to `value`.

`m_value = value` does not set `m_value` to `3`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this condition:

```
if (m_value = 0)
```

even though `m_value` was previously assigned the value of `value`, it's assigned the value `0` here.

You probably meant to compare `m_value` to `0`, like this:

```
if (m_value == 0)
```

If you turn on your compiler warnings (e.g. with `-Wall`), you'll be told that this code is likely a bug.

Comment: @Const Again, if you turn on warnings, the compiler will tell you, and you don't have to look out for it :)